# Unable to deploy my flask app gunicorn on GCP

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, deployment, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my model using Google Cloud Platform using flask on Python. When I'm trying to deploy it I face a 502 Bad Gateway. Checking the log I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
```

I have gunicorn installed on my virtual env. On my requirements.txt :

```
absl-py==2.1.0
astunparse==1.6.3
blinker==1.7.0
cachetools==5.3.2
certifi==2023.11.17
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==3.0.1
flatbuffers==23.5.26
gast==0.5.4
google-api-core==2.15.0
google-auth==2.27.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.2.0
google-cloud-core==2.4.1
google-cloud-storage==2.14.0
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
google-resumable-media==2.7.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.62.0
grpcio==1.60.0
gunicorn==21.2.0
h5py==3.10.0
idna==3.6
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.3
keras==2.15.0
libclang==16.0.6
Markdown==3.5.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.4
ml-dtypes==0.2.0
mtcnn==0.1.1
numpy==1.26.3
oauthlib==3.2.2
opencv-python==4.9.0.80
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==23.2
pillow==10.2.0
protobuf==4.23.4
pyasn1==0.5.1
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
termcolor==2.4.0
typing_extensions==4.9.0
urllib3==2.1.0
Werkzeug==3.0.1
wrapt==1.14.1
```

My app.yaml code :

```
runtime: python311
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

env_variables:
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /app/keys/age-gender-prediction-412516-5f8953183831.json
```

My main.py code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for  
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import cv2
from google.cloud import storage
import tarfile

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

# Set the path to the service account JSON key file within the bucket
json_key_path = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")

# Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = json_key_path

# Google Cloud Storage bucket and file paths for TensorFlow packages
bucket_name = "tensorflow_bucket_import"
tensorflow_package_path = "packages/tensorflow.tar.gz"

# Download TensorFlow packages from Google Cloud Storage
def download_packages():
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Download TensorFlow package
    tensorflow_blob = bucket.blob(tensorflow_package_path)
    tensorflow_blob.download_to_filename("tensorflow.tar.gz")

# Initialize the app by downloading packages
download_packages()

# Extract TensorFlow packages
with tarfile.open("tensorflow.tar.gz", "r:gz") as tar:
    tar.extractall()

# Add the extracted paths to the Python path
tensorflow_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tensorflow')
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = f"{tensorflow_path}"

# Import TensorFlow after updating the Python path
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN


# Obtenez le chemin absolu du dossier des modèles
models_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'models')

# Utilisez des chemins relatifs pour les modèles
age_model_path = os.path.join(models_dir, 'age_model.h5')
gender_model_path = os.path.join(models_dir, 'gender_model.h5')

# Importer le modèle age 
age_model = load_model(age_model_path)
# Importer le modèle gender
gender_model = load_model(gender_model_path)

def process(file, box_expansion=0.05, margin=5):
    # Check if the uploaded file is an image
    allowed_extensions = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
    if '.' in file.filename and file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in allowed_extensions:
        # Open the image file using PIL
        try:
            im = Image.open(file)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error opening image:", e)
            return None

        # Assure que l'image est dans le bon format de couleur (BGR) avant de procéder à la détection du visage avec la bibliothèque MTCNN
        cv_image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(im), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # Create the MTCNN detector
        detector = MTCNN()

        # Detect faces in the image
        faces = detector.detect_faces(cv_image)

        if faces:
            # Utilise le premier visage détecté pour simplifier
            x, y, w, h = faces[0]['box']

            # Étendre la boîte englobante
            expansion_x = int(w * box_expansion)
            expansion_y = int(h * box_expansion)
            x -= expansion_x
            y -= expansion_y
            w += 2 * expansion_x
            h += 2 * expansion_y

            # Ajouter une marge
            x -= margin
            y -= margin
            w += 2 * margin
            h += 2 * margin

            # Assure que la boîte étendue est dans les limites de l'image
            x = max(0, x)
            y = max(0, y)
            w = min(cv_image.shape[1] - x, w)
            h = min(cv_image.shape[0] - y, h)

            # Recadrer et zoomer sur le visage étendu
            face = cv_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

            # Redimensionner le visage à 200x200
            face = cv2.resize(face, (200, 200))

            # Convertir le tableau NumPy en image PIL
            im = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        else:
            # Si aucun visage n'est détecté, afficher un message d'erreur et renvoyer None
            print("Aucun visage n'a été détecté dans l'image.")
            return None

        # Convertir l'image PIL en tableau NumPy
        ar = np.asarray(im)

        # Vérifier si la conversion a abouti à un tableau valide
        if ar is None:
            print("Erreur lors de la conversion de l'image en tableau.")
            return None

        # Convertir le type de données du tableau en float32
        ar = ar.astype('float32')

        # Normaliser les valeurs des pixels dans la plage [0, 1]
        ar /= 255.0

        # Remodeler le tableau pour correspondre à la forme d'entrée attendue par le modèle
        ar = ar.reshape(-1, 200, 200, 3)

        return ar

    else:
        print("Extension de fichier invalide.")
        return None

# Define a route for handling both GET and POST requests to the root URL
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Handle the POST request here (i.e., when the form is submitted)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            # Process and predict with the file 
            ar = process(file)
            age = age_model.predict(ar)
            gender = np.round(gender_model.predict(ar))
            if gender == 0:
                gender = 'Male'
            elif gender == 1:
                gender = 'Female'
            return render_template('result.html', age=age, gender=gender, image_path=url_for('static', filename=f'uploads/{file.filename}'))
    
    # Handle the GET request here (i.e., when the page is initially loaded)
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/detect_age_gender', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def detect_age_gender():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']

        # Save the file to the 'static/uploads' folder
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(file.filename))
        file.save(file_path)

        # Use process function
        ar = process(file)

        if ar is None:
            return "Erreur lors du traitement de l'image : veuillez vérifier que la photo est dans un format valide et qu'un visage est présent."

        # Predict age and gender using the provided models
        age = age_model.predict(ar)
        gender_prediction = np.round(gender_model.predict(ar))

        if gender_prediction not in [0, 1]:
            return "Erreur lors de la prédiction du genre : le modèle a renvoyé une valeur inattendue."

        # Convert gender prediction to 'Male' or 'Female'
        gender = 'Male' if gender_prediction == 0 else 'Female'

        # Return result to the "result" page HTML
        return render_template('result.html', age=age, gender=gender, image_path=url_for('static', filename=f'uploads/{file.filename}'))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)"
```

If someone can help my i'll be very gratefull. If you need more info tell me please. Thanks a lot

I've spent too much time trying to solve the issue but I can't find the problem.

Comment: Because the first time I tried to deploy a model I used GCP and it worked fine. But this time I have a bigger project and I'm struggling to deploy it. It's just for a personal project and GCP was fine.

Comment: 1) The stack trace is incomplete. 2) Your requirements.txt does not specify each Python package that your app requires. 3) Tip: on your local system create a new Python virtual environment and test locally. This will help you with required packages.

Comment: @DanielViglione - AWS and Azure are very good cloud platforms. However, unqualified statements such as `far superior` are not productive.

Comment: @JohnHanley
Actually I already test it locally and it works fine. The problem with GCP is that I can't upload more than 10 000 files so that's why I have to bypass it through Google Cloud Storage (I import tensorflow from Google Cloud). My requirement.txt was not complete cause the rest of my packages were not relevant. I updated it.
I'm kinda new in deploying
And wat do you mean by "The stack trace is incomplete" ?

Comment: Why are you deploying more than 10,000 files? That means you are including files that should not be deployed. For example, the Python package files in the virtual environment should not be included. 2) If you review a Python stack trace, there will be a line telling you what the exception is.

Comment: @JohnHanley It's because I use a pre-trained model from MTCNN that requiere tensorflow. And when I install tensorflow in my virtual env I have more than 10K files. So my solution was to store it in google cloud storage. But maybe there is another way for me to deploy my project on internet ?

Comment: Do not include files from the virtual env. Instead, specify packages in requirements.txt. Make sure you are using a `.gcloudignore` file. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

Comment: @JohnHanley Oh, so I don't need to upload my venv files ? I can just put the requierements.txt ? I see! Awesome I didn't know. I'm gonna try this thanks

Comment: Some Python packages go through a compilation and/or configuration process during installation that is dependent on the machine. That means you should not copy those packages. Let the installer (requirements.txt) handle the setup process on the target system. That also makes your deployments are lot smaller.

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried, it's working fine on my PC (local) but when I try to deploy on GCP I got this error : `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-intel==2.15.0 (from versions: 0.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-intel==2.15.0 ` Why can't he find a version while on my pc he can ?

Comment: Your requirements.txt file specifies absolute version numbers, which means the installer cannot choose the best version for all packages. Most likely one of the packages cannot be installed due to conflicts. Double-check which Python version you are using locally and in App Engine. Always test with the same version. As a test, remove all the version declarations from requirements.txt and redeploy.